# Why isnt my EditorTemplate binding a List on [HttpPost], but renders it fine on [HttpGet]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have uploaded my code to pastebin, this is the link:

http://pastebin.com/wBu9PP2x

When i submit a form, the Lists that i use are not bound to my ViewModel.

But when i send the ViewModel to the view, it renders fine using EditorFor. I have read that when using EditorTemplates, it is supposed to name the List appropriately so that they are bound to the ViewModel automatically upon postback.

The HTML output can be seen here:

http://pastebin.com/5KeyNXWC

Notice that the ViewModel derives from ShowQuestionViewModel, which contains some strings. These strings get bound perfectly.

This is the tutorial i have been following:

http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3

In the tutorial, the MVC framework knows how to bind lists inside of a ViewModel.

Here are some debugger outputs:

Controller takes ShowQuestionViewModel as parameter:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/803/debug.jpg

Controller takes FormCollection as parameter:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/formcollection.png

Different Controller that takes a List and FormCollection as parameter:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/listtest.png

Dont give up on me guys!!

Thanks!

## Solution

I have found this solutin myself. I forgot to use Properties for the rows and columns list in the ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel. Also, the ActionController wont bind without TryUpdateModel() so thanks to @Adam Tuliper as well as the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned lists are you sure your model Upon postback contains all of the expected items? Also remembe the HTML helpers will use modelstate to bind data from as well if you are showing data after a post and not redirecting.

Comment: I made a constructor with FormCollection as the parameter. The FormCollection contains all the expected items. The only problem is that it wont bind to a ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel when i try to use that :/

Comment: So if you try a TryUpdateModel() - what properties specifically are missing? all?

Comment: This is what happens when i TryUpdateModel() with ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/803/debug.jpg/ --- And this is what happens with FormCollection: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/formcollection.png/ -- If i create a Controller and a View that take List<MatrixRows> and try to post that back here is what happens (it knows how to bind): http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/listtest.png/

Comment: I can see that the FormCollection which uses the ViewModel has rows[0].Row_Number where as the one that is binding correctly is without the text: rows - I use the same EditorTemplate to show both though.

Comment: Edited my question with a solution. Why doesnt it bind without using TryUpdateModel() ?